# Passing SEQUENCE NUMBER start from local variable RPGLE -> DB2

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400, rpgle

im trying to use a number stored on a local varibale on my RPGLE program as the start number for a DB2 sequence. Is this posible?. Something like:

```
Exec SQL
   create sequence MySequence
   start with :MYVAR
   increment by 1
   no maxvalue
   no cycle;
```

is a no-no for the compiler. Any ideas?.

Last, using DB2 how can i get the LAST number of the sequence after using it? I need to save that number to a DTAARA for keeping.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a host variable in the `start with` clause of the `create sequence` statement. But that statement can be dynamically prepared. So you could do this:

```
dcl-s myvar          Packed(5:0);
dcl-s stmt           Varchar(512);

stmt = 'create sequence MySequence ' +
          'start with ' + %char(myvar) +
          'increment by 1 ' +
          'no maxvalue ' +
          'no cycle';
exec sql execute immediate :stmt;
```

Generally concatenating an SQL statement like this is an SQL injection risk, but if `myvar` is a numeric variable, then, in this case, there is no risk of injection.